# Automation script for creating NuGet packages

Tags: beginner, powershell, automation

I've been creating some NuGet packages recenly and to automate the process I created the following script that:

- reads the package id from the script name
- reads the package version from the nuspec file
- can rebuild the solution, create a package and upload it by specifying the `jkl`parameters where:

  - j - 0/1 - disables/enables project rebuild
  - k - 0/1 - disables/enables package creation
  - l - 0/1 - disables/enables package upload to the server

Usage:

```
./MyPackage.ps1 110
```

This would create a package called `MyPackage` with rebuilding the solution but not uploading it to the server yet

```
param([String]$cmd)

$build = $cmd.Substring(0,1) -eq "1"
$pack = $cmd.Substring(1,1) -eq "1"
$push = $cmd.Substring(2,1) -eq "1"

$packageId=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

[xml]$nuspec = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\$packageId.nuspec
$version = $nuspec.SelectSingleNode("//package/metadata/version").InnerText

if ($build)
{
    msbuild `
        /t:Rebuild `
        /nologo `
        /p:Configuration=Release `
        /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.2 `
        /p:Platform="Any CPU" `
        /p:OutDir="$PSScriptRoot\lib\net452" `
        `"$PSScriptRoot\..\Foo.sln`"
}

if ($pack)
{
    nuget pack `
        $PSScriptRoot\$packageId.nuspec `
        -properties configuration=release `
        -outputdirectory C:\NuGet\packages\
}

if ($push)
{
    nuget push `
        C:\NuGet\packages\$packageId.$version.nupkg `
        -configfile $PSScriptRoot\NuGet.config
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the rationale for the "110"-style parameter. That seems very user-unfriendly. What is the reason for it?

Comment: @Dangph it's explained in the question. Each position enables respectively  _build|pack|push_ - it's quicker to type and easy to remember because this is the order of package creation so _110_ means _build|pack|don't push_ or _001_ means _don't build|don't pack|push_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parameters**

You could achieve something similar by making real parameters with boolean values such that you can type `MyPackage.ps1 1 1 0`; feeding 3 positional, named, parameters at a cost of two presses of the space bar.

It's not that much slower to type and makes it a lot easier to understand the code (in my opinion).

In addition, you're easily able to add parameter help.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [Boolean]$Build,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
    [Boolean]$Pack,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 3)]
    [Boolean]$Push
)
```

Make $Build default to true perhaps and you have a "Control+Shift+B"-able script.

**Ticks**

I'd consider killing off those ` you have everywhere. A misplaced space after one would break those very easily.

I would generate arguments as an array and feed the call operator. For calls to internal PowerShell commands I would favour splatting for long parameter lists.

```
$packArgs = @(
    'pack'
    "$PSScriptRoot\$packageId.nuspec"
    "-properties", "configuration=release"
    "-outputdirectory", "C:\NuGet\packages\"
)
& nuget $packArgs
```

**XML handler**

Perhaps consider using Select-Xml as it can read directly from a file.

**GetFileNameWithoutExtension**

There's an alternative perhaps:

```
([System.IO.FileInfo]$pscommandpath).BaseName
```

Or, of course, the original but derived from $pscommandpath.

**Alternative approaches**

This is a simple build script, but had you looked at psake? https://github.com/psake/psake.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I really need to implement them. As to psake... this requires a longer study ;-]